# Angular http guide error handling - mistake?

Tags: angular, error-handling, angular-httpclient

I read this guide here: https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-error-details

And in the snippet the guide provides the code tries to differentiate: a) client side error (like no connection etc) and b) backend responses (see code in the guide or in the pic below).

I did implement this code for my case and surprisingly when I do offline mode in Chrome dev tools (set offline flag) - I catch those errors as "backend" errors while I thought it should be the client error.

See below what error I get and my code snippet (same as in the guide):

[image]

This is a snapshot of the console.log - where clearly this message "Backend returned..." should have been shown if there was in fact server side response.

What am i missing here?
Is this code: err.error instanceof Error - even valid?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example seems to be a little outdated. `HttpClient` uses [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) backend under the hood and what the documentation refers to as client side error is `XHR` errors delivered through the `error` callback:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.error = handler()
```

According [to the spec](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#event-xhr-error), `XHR` errors are instances of [ProgressEvent](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#progressevent) interface, so the this check should be added:

```
if (e.error instanceof Error || e.error instanceof ProgressEvent) { }
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your response, I did see the ProgressEvent was logged during those errors and was wondering!:) So am I right to say that current guide at angular.io is not up to date then?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko, yeah, I [created a pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/21378).

Comment: As of today, e.error instanceof ProgressEvent returns false. I wonder why. Based on the debug watch, it is a ProgressEvent but the statement e.error instanceof ProgressEvent returns false!

Comment: @hjchin, interesting, thanks. Can you maybe create a stackblitz demo? I just checked the spec and it hasn't changed so an error should be an instance of ProgressEvent

Comment: I have the same issue, console.log of e.error is showing a ProgressEvent but instanceof is returning false. see  https://github.com/IsraelHikingMap/Site/issues/1660 @MaxKoretskyi did you find a solution for this